# Getting unexpected result by Simple xml element

Tags: php, simplexml

```
$sxe = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents('test1.xml'),'SimpleXMLElement',LIBXML_PARSEHUGE );
```

Below is the xml i am parsing using above code
iam not able to paste xml here but paste the node that causing error

```
<pbs:root xmlns:pbs="http://schema.pbs.gov.au">
```

Getting result:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[@attributes] => Array
    (
        [version] => 2.12
        [vocab-version] => 2015-09-08-01
    )

)
```

But it should contain all the nodes present in xml.

Although if i removed only pbs:root node and keep rest of the xml as it is, it gives me the correct result as i am expecting contains all the nodes

Comment: iam not able to paste my xml here..

Comment: why can't you ?

Comment: getting some error from stackoverflow site...validation alert as it is big file..

Comment: then upload it somewhere and copy a link and paste it to your answer

Comment: can you help without seeing xml..actually issue is adding xmlns:pbs="http://schema.pbs.gov.au" to node ,if added then only @atrributes arrys return else complete node element of xml file

Comment: Do not use `print_r` or `var_export` to debug SimpleXML objects; they can't "see" the internal data in the object. Just try to access the elements you know should be there, or use [this debug library I wrote](https://github.com/IMSoP/simplexml_debug/).

Comment: @ Blueblazer172 ....thanks ....yes you are write simple xml element can not be debug with print_r and var_dump...your library looks good....that works for me and thanks again you save lots of my time ...i have been stuck from may days